# Application crashes on reading a number in string

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

So i have a google spreedsheet from where I'm reading some data. So e.g my first column looks something like this:

[image]

When I change any of the rows into some random string like "abc" my application crashes: 
[image]

I have also recorded a short video where I demonstrate this in action, and put my method in TRY-CATCH so the app doesn't crash. This is very strange... Is it maybe because of the variable *var* where if half of the data array is an integer value, then it becomes int or what else could it be?

http://screencast.com/t/7OlDOzDZX70R

If I, for example put all rows in some strings "a","b" and insert a number in between, the app crashes again...

[image]

I just don't know what might be the problem. It also happens in other rows...

crash report
[image]

Here is my code that deserilazes the json when I get it from the web:

```
  private async Task GetDataAsync()
    {
        //if (this._table.Count != 0) return;

        this.Table.Clear();
        var jsonObject = await DownloadSpreadsheet.GetJson();
        for (int row = 0; row < jsonObject["rows"].Count(); row++)
        {

            Table table = new Table();

            table.Day = jsonObject["rows"][row]["c"][0]["v"].ToString();

            table.Month = jsonObject["rows"][row]["c"][5]["v"].ToString();
            table.Year = jsonObject["rows"][row]["c"][6]["v"].ToString();
            table.People = jsonObject["rows"][row]["c"][7]["v"].ToString();


            this.Table.Add(table);
        }
```

And here is the model where all fields are clearly declared as STRING...

```
 public class Table
{
    [DataMember(Name="id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name="day")]
    public string Day { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name="month")]
    public string Month { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name="year")]
    public string Year { get; set; }
}
```

Here is also the method for getting the json:

```
public class DownloadSpreadsheet 
{
    // 1tJ64Y8hje0ui4ap9U33h3KWwpxT_-JuVMSZzxD2Er8k
    private static readonly string spreadsheetKey = "1Ka-8bTSo4E7sNmsP41prSQqpjawooAvajnFnLi-jtCI";
    private static string jsonUrlTemplate = "http://spreadsheets.google.com/a/google.com/tq?key={0}";
    async public static Task<JObject> GetJson()
    {
        var url = string.Format(jsonUrlTemplate, spreadsheetKey);
        var client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.GetAsync(new Uri(url));
        var rawResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        int start = rawResult.IndexOf("{", rawResult.IndexOf("{") + 1);
        int end = rawResult.LastIndexOf("}");
        String jsonResponse = rawResult.Substring(start, end - start);
        return JObject.Parse(jsonResponse);
    }
}
```

Comment: To answer your question, it'd be useful to know: What kind of crash? What exception is thrown? Which line, if you know?

Comment: What json structure will be returned on `DownloadSpreadsheet.GetJson();` in which line crashes your application?

Comment: I added the crash report

Comment: I added the method for the JSON method also

Comment: I applaud the use of pictures, but for exceptions that where it fails, can you provide the exception and its stack trace instead?

Answer (score 0):

There is no error catching or checking for null values anywhere in the code and an unknown error is occuring.

I moved out your code into linqpad and I get an exception on this line:

```
var result = jsonObject.Result;

    for (int row = 0; row < result["rows"].Count(); row++)
    {     
         table.Day = result["rows"][row]["c"][0]["v"].ToString(); // Exception here
```

the exception is this

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot access child value on
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue.

I recommend that you put error checking into your code and a way to see the message such as:

```
private async Task GetDataAsync()
{
        //if (this._table.Count != 0) return;
   try
   {
        this.Table.Clear();
        var jsonObject = await DownloadSpreadsheet.GetJson();
        for (int row = 0; row < jsonObject["rows"].Count(); row++)
        {

            Table table = new Table();

            table.Day = jsonObject["rows"][row]["c"][0]["v"].ToString();

            table.Month = jsonObject["rows"][row]["c"][5]["v"].ToString();
            table.Year = jsonObject["rows"][row]["c"][6]["v"].ToString();
            table.People = jsonObject["rows"][row]["c"][7]["v"].ToString();


            this.Table.Add(table);
        }
      }
   catch(Exception ex)
     { this.Error = ex; }
}
```

One other thing, in my version of the code I had to work off of the result of the task `jsonObject.Result` before extracting data.

Comment: I used try-catch and added the video so you can take a look on if you have time. I'm really desperate for why is this happening...